# Loading values into a selectList from controller

Tags: selectlist

I have an AppSettingsController and a VisualForce page and on the page the user enters config settings into the app. Things like a username and password and a web service URL. The web service retrieves data and this data is added to Salesforce as leads.

I want them to set a campaign on the VF page so that the data retrieved from the web service is also added to a specific campaign.

Right now I have added a select list to the page, and in my controller I have added a field to the class, I am assigning the field values but nothing is displayed in the view.

Here is the required info from the page

```
<apex:page Controller="AppSettingController" docType="html-5.0">
    <apex:messages />
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Settings" columns="1">
                <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                    <label>Campaign</label>
                    <apex:selectlist>
                        <apex:selectoptions value="{!campaigns}"/>
                    </apex:selectlist>
                </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>     
</apex:page>
```

And in my controller:

```
public with sharing class AppSettingController
{

    public List<String> campaigns;

    public AppSettingController()
    {
        setView();    
    }

    public void setView()
    {
         campaigns = new List<String>();
         campaigns.add('Campaign test');
    }
}
```

When the page is rendered, the selectlist is just an empty control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of how your controller should be modified to reflect the values.

```
public with sharing class AppSettingController {

        public List<SelectOption> campaigns = new List<SelectOption>();

        public AppSettingController() {
            setView();    
        }

        public void setView() {

             campaigns.add(new SelectOption('Campaign Value', 'Campaign Label'));
             // add other items

        }


        public List<SelectOption> getCampaigns() {
            return campaigns;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your value binding for an `<apex:selectOptions>` needs to return a `List<SelectOption>` rather than a string array.

Additionally, you need to provide a getter method to make the binding available to Visualforce, which you can do synthetically by adding `{ get; set; }` following the definition of a public instance variable.

The reason for using `SelectOption` rather than `String` is that your options typically need to store a display value or label (in your case, the Campaign name) and an internal API value (likely the Campaign Id). You'll pass both values to the `SelectOption` constructor, and the value of the select list element itself will be the API value of the selected `SelectOption`.